# LINQ to entities - Filtering data with IQueryable.Contains

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have been struggling with a problem for some time.
I'm currently moving an old project from entity framework to entity framework core 2.2.4.

In this project, the user can define a lot of search criterias on a web page before he does the request of the data to the server.
I do not enter into much details about the query but it links 5 tables where 2 of the tables contains a list of dynamic name+value parameters (vertically stored in the table). Those parameters are associated to their parent table (entity). 
The query returns a list of unique identifiers. They represent the unique key to one of the parent table.

For my ease and due to the complexity to translate a such request to a LINQ query, i've decided to first construct dynamically the query with the search criterias in a c# string.

In the previous version of the EntityFramework, i've achieved that with:

```
List<string> arrFilteredGlobalId = _dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select GLOBALID from.....").ToList<string>();
```

Then i can do:

```
var full = from bundle in _dbContext.BUNDLE
                where arrFilteredGlobalId.Contains(bundle.GLOBALID)
                select bundle;
int num = full.Count(); // <= works perfectly
```

In the fresh new version of EntityFramework Core, context.Database.SqlQuery does not exist anymore.
I had to do the following in order to achieve the same logic:

1. Declare a new class DBGlobalIdentifier with a single property

```
public class DBGlobalIdentifier
{
    public string GLOBALID { get; set; }
}
```

2. In my context class, i've declared a DbQuery object typed with my class DBGlobalIdentifier previously defined.

```
public virtual DbQuery<DBGlobalIdentifier> Identifiers { get; set; }
```

3. Finally, i do

```
IQueryable<DBGlobalIdentifier> arrFilteredGlobalId =  this._context.Identifiers.FromSql("select GLOBALID from.....");

// DBGlobalIdentifier test = arrFilteredGlobalId.First(); <== works perfectly.

var full = from bundle in _context.Bundles
                where arrFilteredGlobalId.Contains(new DBGlobalIdentifier() { GLOBALID = bundle.GLOBALID })
                select bundle;

int num = full.Count(); // <= it fails and returns an exception (see here under)
```

Exception returned:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryOptimizer.TryOptimizeContains(ResultOperatorBase resultOperator, QueryModel queryModel)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryOptimizer.TryOptimizeContains(ResultOperatorBase resultOperator, QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryOptimizer.VisitResultOperator(ResultOperatorBase resultOperator, QueryModel queryModel, int index)
Remotion.Linq.Clauses.ResultOperatorBase.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel, int index)
Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitResultOperators(ObservableCollection<ResultOperatorBase> resultOperators, QueryModel queryModel)
Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.TransformingQueryModelExpressionVisitor<TVisitor>.VisitSubQuery(SubQueryExpression expression)
Remotion.Linq.Clauses.Expressions.SubQueryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
Remotion.Linq.Clauses.WhereClause.TransformExpressions(Func<Expression, Expression> transformation)
Remotion.Linq.QueryModel.TransformExpressions(Func<Expression, Expression> transformation)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryOptimizer.Optimize(QueryCompilationContext queryCompilationContext, QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.OptimizeQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel, bool asyncQuery)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.OptimizeQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel, bool asyncQuery)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor<TResult>(QueryModel queryModel)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore<TResult>(Expression query, IQueryModelGenerator queryModelGenerator, IDatabase database, IDiagnosticsLogger<Query> logger, Type contextType)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler+<>c__DisplayClass13_0<TResult>.<Execute>b__0()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore<TFunc>(object cacheKey, Func<Func<QueryContext, TFunc>> compiler)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute<TResult>(Expression query)
System.Linq.Queryable.Count<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source)
```

An idea about my problem?

Thank you!
Fred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the problem is not quite interesting - the exception call stack indicates EF Core query translator bug (there are still many). Most likely caused by the (unexpected) usage of `new DBGlobalIdentifier` inside the `Contains`.

The idea with query type is correct. Since `select` raw SQL queries are *composable*, the solution is to extract back the value using `Select` and then use regular `Contains`:

```
var arrFilteredGlobalId = _context.Identifiers
    .FromSql("select GLOBALID from.....")
    .Select(x => x.GLOBALID); // <--

var full = from bundle in _context.Bundles
           where arrFilteredGlobalId.Contains(bundle.GLOBALID)
           select bundle;
```